# How is the parametric curve $x = 1/(1+t^2), y=1/(1+t^2)$ a circle?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the parametric curve $x = 1/(1+t^2), y= 1/(1+t^2), -\infty < t < \infty$, we have that $x(1+t^2) = 1 \implies 1+t^2 = \frac{1}{x} \implies y = x$. I'd look at this as nothing but a straight line starting infinitely close to the origin. However, the book claims its a circle, and moreover, claims that $y = 0$ for $x = 0.$ I am unable to make sense out of this, how can this curve be a circle?

In your answer, please explain why my reasoning fails as well as explaining why the curve is a circle. Thank you.

Comment: would be a very degenerate circle then :-) maybe there is a typo in the book. (actually it's a star $x=-y$ is also part of the set)(please forget the stuff in the last brackets... xD)

Comment: They probably mean $\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the correct parametrization is
$$
x=\frac{1}{1+t^2},\;\;\;y=\frac{t}{1+t^2}
$$
must be a typo...

Comment: ...for crying out loud, yes. Typo in the book, thanks.

Comment: +1 $(x-1/2)^2 +y^2=1/2$. Also, technically a parametrization like this misses one point on the circle. In this case $(0,0)$ is the _limit_ of the parametrization as $t\to\infty$ or $-\infty$, but $(0,0)$ is not in the image. There's no one-to-one continuous map between a line and a compact circle.